# jQuery. Как повесить обработчик на несуществующий элемент для сложного електора

Tags: jquery

Предположим есть такая структура страницы

```
body
    .content
        #dinamical-element 
            div
                div
                    button.action
                        div.title
```

Я хочу навесить событие на кнопку и могу сделать это так:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dinamical-element button', clickHandler);
```

Но, если нужно использовать более сложную выборку, типа (*это исключительно ради примера и код никакого смысла не несет*):

```
var $selector = $('#dinamical-element').find('div.title').parent('button');
```

Каким образом можно использовать подобное для несуществующих на данный момент элементов страницы?

Пробовал так, но такое не пройдет

```
$(document).on('click', $selector, clickHandler)
```

Comment: Никак, обработчик вещается на конкретный элемент DOM'a, если этого элемента нет, то и обработчик никуда не повесится.

Comment: @Vartlok, да неужели? :)

Comment: @Vartlok В первом примере я показал как можно повесить обработчик на несуществующий элемент. Добавить селектор вторым аргументом `on()`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, JILeXanDR оу, посыпаю голову пеплом, был не прав. Можно вешать через селектор. Буду знать =)

Answer (score 2):

Надо преобразовать селектор к такому виду, чтобы он записывался CSS-подобной строкой. К примеру, JQuery имеет псевдоселектор `:has`, который поможет обратить операцию `parent`

Ваш пример можно написать вот так:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dinamical-element button:has(div.title)', ... )
```

В более сложных случаях может помочь упрощение и фильтрация:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dinamical-element button', function (e) {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).children().is('div.title')) {
        ...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Для несуществующих элементов DOM надо использовать delegate, а не on.

```
    $('body').delegate("selector", "click", function (event) { /* do smth */});
```

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.`

http://api.jquery.com/delegate